# How to add columns to another table based on one column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have my shop database and I want to join two tables together.

```
id_order | reference | id_shop_group | id_shop | id_carrier | id_lang | id_customer | id_cart
```

This the header row of my `orders` table and below is the header of `customers` table.

```
id_customer | id_shop_group | id_shop | id_gender | firstname | lastname
```

What I want to do is to join them based on `id_customer` column. More specifically I want to add all columns of `customers` except the ones that are already there to `orders` table based on`id_customer`. After joining the tables should look like this:

```
id_order|reference|id_shop_group|id_shop|id_carrier|id_lang|id_customer|id_cart|id_gender|firstname|lastname
```

When searching for a solution I found `INNER JOIN` keyword, but I'm not sure how to use it the way I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't "Add columns to a table". We, instead, submit SQL to the database that returns the result set that we want. In your case we want to Join the two tables and we can do that using an INNER JOIN on your `id_customer` field that is common between the two tables. We can turn that into it's own table if you want to hold, permanently, those results. It would look something like

```
SELECT 
    orders.id_order,
    orders.reference,
    orders.id_shop_group,
    orders.id_shop,
    orders.id_carrier,
    orders.id_lang,
    orders.id_customer,
    orders.id_cart,
    customer.id_gender,
    customer.firstname,
    customer.lastname
FROM orders INNER JOIN customer on orders.id_customer = customer.id_customer;
```

You can tweak the list of fields to be returned from the joining of these tables to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that id_shop and id_shop_group are in both tables suggests they are part of a composite key.  You may need to join using all three shared columns to guarantee unique rows. Otherwise you may retrieve duplicate order rows where the customer belongs to more than one shop.

e.g.

```
SELECT
...
FROM orders INNER JOIN customer on orders.id_customer = customer.id_customer 
and orders.id_shop_group = customer.id_shop_group
and orders.id_shop = customer.id_shop
```